# How can I deserialize a json in c#

Tags: c#, json, rest

Hello I'm trying to deserialize the following json in c#:

```
{  
 "Labels":[  
    {  
       "DeviceID":9,
       "Disabled":false,
       "Id":0,
       "Internal":"1@CB_I_AllCloseCheck",
       "Label":"CB_I_AllCloseCheck",
       "MAddress":0,
       "Mask":2147483648,
       "ModuleID":4,
       "Offset":0,
       "Position":1,
       "SectionID":0,
       "Type":16
     }
   ]
 }
```

With the following code line:

```
Labels myDeserializedObjList = (Labels)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sub, typeof(Labels));
```

The string sub contains this json like a string. Where my class Labels is the following:

```
public class Labels
    {
        public string DeviceID { get; set; }
        public string Disabled { get; set; }
        public string IValue { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Internal { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string MAddress { get; set; }
        public string Mask { get; set; }
        public string ModuleID { get; set; }
        public string Offset { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string SectionID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

But the result of this operation is all my atributes equal to null. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have an object with a `Labels` property that contains an array of labels. You are trying to deserialize it as if it were a single `Labels` object instead. `Labels` isn't a list

Comment: U need to pack Labels in list (from json). Response u get is `List<Labels> Labels`

Comment: Okay so the code shoueld like this one? List<Labels> myDeserializedObjList = (List<Labels>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sub, typeof(List<Labels>));

Comment: In vs2017 copy your json to the clipboard then choose edit/paste special/paste classes as json.  This will generate classes the perfectly match your json.

Comment: The object you deserialize to has to match your JSON. You can't (easily) deserialize an object into a list type (which is what you're trying to do), or an array into an object. Remember: `{...}` = object, `[...]` = array. Your root is an object because it is declared using `{...}`.

Comment: Once again a Json C# question answered by using Json2Csharp or Visual Studio special paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment your root object is just that: an object. It's not an array. Its only property (Labels) is an array.

You should add an extra "root object" class:

```
public class LabelsContainer
{
    public IList<Labels> Labels {get;set;}
}
```

And then deserialize to that:

```
var labelsContainer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LabelsContainer>(data);
var labels = labelsContainer?.Labels;
```

Answer (score 2):

The JSON string shows an object with a Labels property that contains an array of labels. You need to try something like :

```
class LabelsDTO
{
    public Labels[] Labels{get;set;}
}

...

var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LabelsDTO>(sub);

for (var label in dto.Labels)
{
...
}
```